Логирование кто и какой файл скачивает
Подскажите, где нибудь в битриксе хранится информация по скачиваемым файлам? или как нибудь можно настроить запись этого события?
нужна информация кто и какой файл скачивает
в таблицах b_stat... ничего не нашел, в b_file тоже нет, даже в b_stat_hit не фиксирует скачивания

Сомневаюсь, что такое есть "из коробки", скорее всего Вам придется написать свой логгер. Пример можете посмотреть тут - https://intensa.ru/blog/logirovanie-dlya-razrabotchikov-1s-bitriks/

Если вы для скачивания предоставляете прямую ссылку, то скачивание идёт напрямую средствами сервера, без участия битрикса. Для логирования можно сделать собственную страницу, на которой файл будет выдаваться по ключу файла.
